# React PropTypes: An array of different object shapes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

How would I declare a proptype definition for an array that can contain a set of different object shapes? e.g.,

If I have a component, e.g., `EmailRenderer` that takes a prop called called `sections` that is an array of different objects, each with a unique type and it's associated properties.

```js
const sections = [
    {
        type: "h1",
        copy: "Header!",
    },
    {
        type: "p1",
        copy: "lots of copy....",
    },
    {
        type: "image-main",
        src:
            "http://www.some-image.com",
        alt: "blah",
    },
    {
        type: "button",
        buttonType: "secondary",
        copy: "Watch now!",
        href: "#",
    },
    {
        type: "p1",
        copy: "more copy...",
    },
];

// ...

class EmailRenderer extends React.Component {
  // ...
}

//...

EmailRenderer.propTypes = {
  sections: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    // ???
  )
}

<EmailRenderer sections={sections} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare classes for each of the "types", let's call them `TypographyElement` (copy), `MediaElement` (src), `ButtonElement` (href).

Then the `sections` prop can be declared as

```js
sections : PropTypes.arrayOf(
  PropTypes.oneOf(
   [
      PropTypes.instanceOf(TypographyElement), 
      PropTypes.instanceOf(MediaElement), 
      PropTypes.instanceOf(ButtonElement), 
      ...
   ]
  )
);
```